# What is the purpose of graph collections in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The API discusses [Graph Collections](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#graph-collections) which judging from the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L2071) are a general purpose key/data storage. What is the purpose of those collections?

Comment: Search for "GraphKeys." for some examples of collections: ie TrainableVariables: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L113 , TableInitializers: https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/0.5.0/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py#521, Summaries: https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/python/ops/summary_ops.py#48

Comment: Hi @YaroslavBulatov can you please re-post your link? Last two are broken. Thanks always!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remember that under the hood, Tensorflow is a system for specifying and then executing computational data flow graphs.  The graph collections are used as part of keeping track of the constructed graphs and how they must be executed.  For example, when you create certain kinds of ops, such as `tf.train.batch_join`, the code that adds the op will also add some queue runners to the `QUEUE_RUNNERS` graph collection.  Later, when you call `start_queue_runners()`, by default, it will look at the `QUEUE_RUNNERS` collection to know which runners to start.

Comment: I'm still confused about the concept of collections. By adding different ops into different collections, does it make the op look-up more efficient?
It seems that the collection is only good for grouping or organizing ops together without bringing any "real" benefits to computation, right? Here for "real" I mean if I remove the concept of collection out of tensorflow system, it doesn't hurt the computation.

Comment: No, the point of the collections is not efficiency, the point is book-keeping.  Collections are used to know which variables should be trained.  Or which ops must be called to for training.   Collections are a map from string to set-of-graph-bits.  Several known strings are stored in GraphKeys.  These refer to important sets of graph-bits (i.e., ops, variables, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

I think there are at least two benefits for me so far:

1. when you distribute your program on multiple GPUs or machines it is convenient to collect losses from different devices which are in the same collection. Use the tf.add_n to add them to accumulate the loss.
2. To update a particular set of variables like weights and biases in my own way.

For instance:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
w = tf.Variable([1,2,3], collections=[tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS], dtype=tf.float32)    
w2 = tf.Variable([11,22,32], collections=[tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS], dtype=tf.float32)
weight_init_op = tf.variables_initializer(tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
weight_init_op.run()
for vari in tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS): 
    tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, vari.assign(0.2 * vari))
weight_update_ops = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
for op in weight_update_ops:
    print(op.eval())
```

The output:

```
[0.2 0.4 0.6]
[2.2 4.4 6.4]
```

Comment: Small note on your code... when you start an tf.InteractiveSession(), why don't you take benefit from that?

As in... use weight_init_op.run(), and weight_update_ops.eval()

Comment: @zwep Yeah, you are right. Maybe I idon't know that trick when I wrote this.; Anyway my code works.